# calling javascript function from PHP inside HTML body element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

please help me. 
I used to do some programming ages ago in PHP3 and now I am slowly getting on track again, using new features like jquery. 
I made class for dealing with errors on the site, which works pretty fine, but now I have problem with simple peace of code which should deal with error itself. I made simple class function : (..part of the switch () )

```
default :
echo('<script type="javascript">
$("#infoLine").show  ("clip", 300, "vertical");
$("#infoLine" ).text("'.$this->strErrorInfo.'");
$("#infoLine").addClass(".error");
</script>');
```

This part doesn't works Script part appears in html code, div with id infoLine is defined in the code like this:

```
<footer>
    <div id="infoLine"></div>
</footer>
```

error generating code is:

```
<section id="main"><div style="float:none; position: relative;">
<?php
$error->intErrorOnLine = 15795;
$error->strErrorInfo = "This is really big error! Everything works fine";
$error->strErrorInFile = "some.html";
$error->showErrorLine();
```

css added to the code is like:

```
#infoLine {

display: none;
position: relative;
bottom: 2em;
width: 95%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
max-height: 50px;

}
.error {

position: relative;
bottom: 2em;
width: 95%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
max-height: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #bb0000;
border-width: 2px;
background: rgba(255, 150, 150, 0.8);

}
```

div msg will never appear and I don't know why. I know I do something really stupid, so please don't beat me :) - thank you very much for any help

Comment: if that is in a switch statement, make sure that the other switch cases aren't being called. default will only happen if no other case matches.

Comment: I have checked it out and this part works fine. I can even see result in browsers html code but function itself is not running.

Comment: Can you add the code for the switch statement? The css styles are largely irrelevant to the question.   For example is the switch inside the class with the property `strErrorInfo` I have to assume it is or `$this` is not correct.  Also it's generally a bad practice to echo output from inside a class file.

Comment: You need to echo your script after the `#infoLine` element in the dom or wrap your jQuery in a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event. The spaces between `.show` and `("clip` may also be the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will check it tonight after work.

Comment: you should also make sure you're including jquery on each page

Comment: Thank you very much for a help. It works now - My fault was to call function before element has been created - I changed position of an element in main html code and everything works as expected - really appreciate your time and useful hints - thank you again guys!!